# Creating a Temporary Cron Job From the Terminal

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cron

Is there a way to create a temporary one-time only cron job from the command line? I'd like to have an egg-timer like function to open a terminal and do:

```
notify "time is up" 30
```

which would simply run this after 30 minutes:

```
zenity --info --text="time is up"
```

It seems easy enough for me to create, but I'm having a hard time believing no one has created something similar. Searching Ubuntu's repository for timing packages doesn't show anything. Has this been done before?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you know that your `$DISPLAY` will be the same, you can do:

```
echo "DISPLAY=$DISPLAY zenity --info --text=\"time is up\"" | at now + 30 minutes
```

Providing the environment variable in this way will make it available to `zenity` when it's run.

Answer (score 9):

Use the `at` command.

```
$ at now + 30 minutes
at> zenity --info --text="time is up"
at> ^D     (press CTRL-D)
```

The time format is pretty flexible. Here are a bunch of examples.

```
$ at 11:45

$ at 0800 Friday

$ at 4pm + 3 days

$ at 9am tomorrow
```

Comment: at doesn't appear to have the correct variables defined to launch X programs.

Comment: at jobs are supposed to inherit all the same environment variables that are set when you initiate the job, but since it will be run by the `atd' service, it won't be attached to your X display. You may be out of luck there. See my other answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could write yourself a little script.

```
#! /bin/bash
sleep $(($2 * 60))
zenity --info --text="$1"
```

Make it executable and run it from the command line:

```
./notify "Time is up" 30
```

Comment: and it case it's not clear to the op, you can similarly just do sleep 1800;zenity --info --text="$1"

Answer (score 0):

at. http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?at

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't really help. Can at launch X programs? A simple example like echo "zenity --info --text=\"time is up\"" | at -t "201011141811" fails to do anything.